# partial view rendering inside the form tag above

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

partial tag above code is render inside the form tag when page is loading , not sure how I can solve this , replacing the partial tag place is not working .

I tried to changes the partial tag place in code , but it is not working also

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="main" 
action="@ViewData["MainFormAction"]" method="post"                 
class="form">
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(SiteHeader))

@RenderSection("PageTitleAndMenu", required: true)

@RenderBody()
</form>
<partial name="_MainMenuPartial" />
```

Comment: where do you want the partial view should be rendered? after the form tag?

Comment: `partial tag above code is render inside the form tag` means you wanna use <Partial /> inside <form></form>?

Comment: @KhizarIqbal @ xinran  , I want render partial view after the form tag, but somehow it is rendering inside the form tag when I checked in DOM. so it is affecting my UI

Comment: Can you provide a minimal executable demo to restore your problem?

Comment: can you try this out? I've excludeed action part `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="main" method="post" class="form">`

Comment: it is because it loads asynchronously, make synchronous using @html.partial